# Error when trying to run on device, .app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework: unknown failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode

I was trying to product>archive the built app. But when I did that, I receive the  error

> .app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework: unknown error
>   -1=ffffffffffffffff Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

Which says pod frameworks are missing, but I have installed them all. And also can see the GTM session fetch on Targets in the Pod project.
[image]
[image]

But also I see that under frameworks folder, GTM session Fetcher file is highlighted in red. I'm not sure how to proceed further to run on my iTouch. (iOS 9.3 version).

Made the deployment to 9.3 version. Build Architechture are set to No as well. Is there any I can do successfully run on my device? Also tried Pod reinstall, pod update. Then went on to pod deintegrate and then install once more. Removed derived data as well.

Complete error issue:

> Code Signing
>   /Users/rajesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Conversa-duxqgsmwlzqluzedbqokeyjaguzp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Conversa.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework
>   with Identity iPhone Developer: Rajesh Sundaram (759ZS324FB)
>   /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign
>   86D08F3535FEA4B5F4507E4C5C61A30ACDF16B5E 
>   --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/rajesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Conversa-duxqgsmwlzqluzedbqokeyjaguzp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Conversa.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework'
>   /Users/rajesh/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Conversa-duxqgsmwlzqluzedbqokeyjaguzp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Conversa.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework:
>   unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff Command /bin/sh failed with exit
>   code 1

Comment: try to clean **ctrl+command+k** and build first before run.

Comment: Tried that. Unfortunately didn't help me.

Comment: than try to reinstall your pods. after that again same ctrl+command+k and just build.

Comment: another thing is to clear your derived data.

Comment: Okay, gonna try them now.

Comment: Delete your project's .xcodeproj file, then run pod install command. Open .xcodeproj file again which is newly created. It may resolve your issue.

Comment: After deleting .xcodeproj file, I could not install pod. It asks me path to xcodeproj for isntalling. Did you mean I have to delete the workspace?

Comment: no, you have to delete .xcworkspace file just.

Comment: Umm. Couldn't make this work.